# blank screen when i hit ng build command

Tags: angular, ng-build

i have try all possible ng related commands bt nothing will happen only blank screen apperas with some text at bottom my node version 8.16.1 
VS code version 1.38.1

[image]

Comment: did you try window's command console or powershell console ? If it works there then your problem is with Visual code not with ng cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved | i just echo -e "export PATH=$(npm prefix -g)/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc command
and upgrade install **npm install -g @angular/cli@7.2.12** version